# Pdflib Issue with the table

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, pdflib

I have an issue with this table. When I want to position it on the center of PDF, it launches this error:

> Calculated table width 170 too large

so my following code:

```
$searchpath = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/input";

$outfile = "";

$title = "Vertical Text Alignment";
$tf=0; $tbl=0; 
/* Define the column widths of the first and the second column */
$c1 = 50; $c2 = 120;$c3 = 80;


/* Define the lower left and upper right corners of the table instance.

 * The table width of 200 matches the sum of the widths of the two table

 * columns 80 + 120.

 */

$llx=250; $lly=800; $urx=300; $ury=50;
```

Comment: Where in this code are you doing table creation? And are you aware that the width of the thing you create is only 50? ($urx - $llx)

Comment: i add other code if possible i can share with you ,can you tell me your @

Comment: It would be better to share the relevant code pieces on here so that people with more experience with pdfLib can take a look at this as well...

Comment: yes i will share so if possible to help or passe on chat